# Flutter Expand/Occupy TextFormField to Fill Rest of Screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a form with some TextFormField, and I want to expand the last TextFormField to occupy the rest of the screen. This last TextFormField can have multiple lines of text.

I haven't been able to achieve this, and have tried `SizedBox.expand()` and the `Expanded` widget, but no luck.

[image]

Below is the current code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "What is this new classroom?"
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
            Expanded(
              child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: "Classroom Name",
                        hintText: "What's name of the new classroom?",
                      ),
                    )
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: "Description",
                        hintText: "Description of the new classroom",
                      ),
                      //maxLines: 5,
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I edited your code a bit. But **it didn't work**. Please refer the below code. I will try to **explain my understanding** below the code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("What is this new classroom?"),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: "Classroom Name",
                        hintText: "What's name of the new classroom?",
                      ),
                    )),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      maxLines: null,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: "Description",
                        hintText: "Description of the new classroom",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I inspected the view with your code. `TextField` which is inside `TextFormField` is not occupying the rest of the screen. So I edited to have `TextField` to have the rest of the screen. The above code does that. See the inspected view
[image]

But the there is `InputDecorator` (which is child of our TextField) which draws the border line. In our case, it draws the border line based on content.

Possible workarounds could be:

1. `maxLines = null` which will grow the `TextField` as the content groups. But initial view will be one line.
2. Give fixed `maxLines` (as 10 or 20) which might look like occupying the screen. But it is not dynamic(doesn't change based on screen size / screen orientation)

Comment: Both approaches have their limitations, but I can't work out anything better. +1 for using the inspector!

Answer (score 3):

I found solution, maybe it can help someone. You can create Container or another widget with border same like TextField and make it expanded to fill whole Screen and above that with Stack widget put TextField with maxLines: null and without border.

[EDIT] It works also without Stack widget. Here is my code

```
Expanded(
                  child: Material(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),                      
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: TextField(                         
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,  
                        hintText: "Description",                         
                      ),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      maxLines: null,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 2):

```dart
expands: true,
```

Solves your problem:) Here is the code for the expanded text field:

```dart
TextField(
    maxLines: null,
    expands: true,
    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
)
```

Comment: The textAlignVertical property here is very handy, all answers above will have the text cursor in the middle of the box when we focus the text field. Setting to TextAlignVertical.Top will shift the cursor to the start of the text field.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set `contentPadding` after widgets are rendered using `addPostFrameCallback` inside `initState()`.
But you will have to calculate new height manually based on positions and heights of all above widgets.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _tffKey1 =
      GlobalKey();
  final _tffKey2 = GlobalKey();
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();
  final _textKey = GlobalKey();
  double _height = 0;

  //Set callback that will be called after widgets are rendered.
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      final RenderBox scaffoldKeyBox = _scaffoldKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      final RenderBox tffBox = _tffKey1.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      final RenderBox textBox = _textKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      final tffPos = tffBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
      final textPos = textBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

      //Calculate widget's height.
      _height = (scaffoldKeyBox.size.height -
          (tffBox.size.height + tffPos.dy) -
          (textBox.size.height + textPos.dy));

      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "What is this new classroom?",
              key: _textKey,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child:
                    ListView(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        key: _tffKey1,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: "Classroom Name",
                          hintText: "What's name of the new classroom?",
                        ),
                      )),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      key: _tffKey2,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, top: _height), // Set new height here
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: "Description",
                        hintText: "Description of the new classroom",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a litte bit late, but the answer has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50024552/4157431).
You just need the following

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: whatever,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

TextFormField contains [expands](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/expands.html) property.

```
Expanded(
  child: TextFormField(
    //...
    maxLines: null,
    expands: true,
)),
```

When you set `expands` property to true, you must set `maxLines` to `null`. Then, to make it work, wrap `TextFormField` inside `Expanded`.

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple

```
TextFormField(
    expands: true,  // add this line
    minLines: null, // add this line
    maxLines: null, // add this line
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      // If you want to change text form field background color  
      // add these two lines
      fillColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      filled: true,
    ),
  )
```